# Grafana multivalue float histogram_quantile

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-templating

Hi I'm forcing problem with histogram_quantile. If I'll set my variable to multi-value so I can repeat panels. Then I got error which says

> parse error at char 21: unexpected character: '\'

My request is:

```
histogram_quantile($percentile, avg((rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{instance=~"$server"}[1m]))) by (le, application))
```

**$Percentile** variable is initiated as custom with values as below and multi-value selected

```
0.9, 0.5, 0.99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The histogram_quantile function requires a single floating point number as an input, and the multi-value feature of Grafana will produce something like `0\.9|0\.5|0\.99` which is not a floating point number. You will need to use multiple expressions for this.

Answer (score 3):

The default format for variables escape the `.` with a backslash, so `0.5` becomes `0\.5`.

To not escape `.`, you can use another format on the variable like this: `${percentile:raw}`.

[More information on format options here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/).